# Terraform Kubernetes dial tcp 127.0.0.1:80

Tags: kubernetes, terraform

I recently created a cluster in GKE with terraform, all the provider configuration is configured fine, after the creation of the cluster with terraform apply,  I tried just to run a terraform plan, I expected the output to be nothing to change, all up to date, but the output I got was this:

```
Error: Get "http://localhost/api/v1/namespaces/external-istiod": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:80: connect: connection refused │  │   with module.k8s_istio.kubernetes_namespace.external_istiod, │   on ../../../../../../shared/modules/gke/istio/main.tf line 54, in resource "kubernetes_namespace" "external_istiod": │   54: resource "kubernetes_namespace" "external_istiod" {
```

That's very odd, it seems terraform is trying to hit kubernetes api trough localhost, but my config file is configured fine, my config provider.tf file looks like this:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    google = {
      source  = "hashicorp/google"
      version = "~> 4.40.0"
    }

    google-beta = {
      source  = "hashicorp/google-beta"
      version = "~> 5.1.0"
    }
  }

  backend "gcs" {
    bucket = "my-terraform-state"
    prefix = "my-repo/gcp/clusters/my-cluster"
  }
}

provider "google" {
  project = var.metadata.project
  region  = var.metadata.region
}

provider "google-beta" {
  project = var.metadata.project
  region  = var.metadata.region
}
```

Besides, I successfully created the cluster on GKE with this provider file and configuration, why is it returning me this error now? I researched a lot of issues on github and I did actually find some bypasses to this, either way I want to know what's happening and fix it correctly instead just bypassing.

I was expecting the command `terraform plan` to return `No changes. Your infrastructure is up-to-date.` But instead I got the dial tcp error.

My gke/istio/main.tf looks like this:

```
data "google_client_config" "current" {
}


data "kubernetes_secret" "service_account" {
  provider = kubernetes.cluster

  metadata {
    name      = kubernetes_secret_v1.istio_reader_sa_token.metadata.0.name
    namespace = "external-istiod"
  }

  depends_on = [kubernetes_service_account.istio_reader]
}

provider "kubernetes" {
  alias                  = "cluster"
  host                   =  var.cluster_endpoint
  token                  =  data.google_client_config.current.access_token
  cluster_ca_certificate =  var.cluster_ca_certificate
}

provider "kubernetes" {
  alias                  = "istio"
  host                   = var.istio_endpoint
  token                  = var.istio_cluster_token
  cluster_ca_certificate = base64decode(var.istio_cluster_ca_certificate)
}

resource "kubernetes_namespace" "external_istiod" {
  provider = kubernetes.cluster

  metadata {
    name = "external-istiod"
    annotations = {
      "topology.istio.io/controlPlaneClusters" = "*"
    }
  }
}
```

Cluster endpoint is being setted at:

```
data "google_container_cluster" "cluster" {
  name     = var.cluster.name
  location = var.metadata.region

  depends_on = [ module.cluster ]
}

module "k8s_istio" {
  source = "../../../../../../shared/modules/gke/istio"

  cluster_name           = var.cluster.name
  cluster_ca_certificate = base64decode(data.google_container_cluster.cluster.master_auth[0].cluster_ca_certificate)
  cluster_endpoint       = "https://${data.google_container_cluster.cluster.endpoint}"

}
```

Comment: `kubernetes_namespace` is from the `kubernetes` provider but that's not in your provider list above.

Comment: @jordanm Thanks for the response! I have provider kubernetes set on the file gke/istio/main.tf, I will update the question with that configuration

Comment: How are you setting the `cluster_endpoint` variable?

Comment: It's a variable, that depends on the cluster module @jordanm I updated the question with the information

Comment: I think the problem may be with   token = data.google_client_config.current.access_token

take a look at scenario B of the hashicorp docs https://support.hashicorp.com/hc/en-us/articles/4408936406803-Kubernetes-Provider-block-fails-with-connect-connection-refused-